# Why I can push a lot into a small stack without error?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 8
ExitProcess PROTO,dwExitCode:DWORD

.data

.code
main proc
    mov ecx,1024
l1: push ax
    loop l1
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
END main
```

The intention here is that I am testing about the size of stack, and trying to create a stack overflow. I set the stack size deliberately to a very small value, and push a lot into stack, but turn out to find that this code is accepted by MASM and runs correctly without any error message. It seems that whatever size of stack is irrelevant here, and no matter how much you push into stack the code will run anyway.

I feel like this problem have something to do with dynamic stack size, that stack always start from `0xFFFFFFFF`(virtual memory), and can grow as long as it do not colide into something(heap), which makes setting the stack size become a nonsense directive.

Comment: AFAIK, the `.stack` directive is for when using a segmented memory model - which you are not. If you dump the PE header using something like `objdump -x myapp.exe`, you'll see that `SizeOfStackReserve` and `SizeOfStackCommit` probably are way larger than 8. If you really want to modify those fields, you could do so with the `/STACK` linker option (e.g. pass `/STACK:8,8` to `link`). I don't remember if Windows has a minimum allowed stack size for applications.

Comment: You really aren't pushing a lot — only 2 KB. The page size is 4 KB so probably the stack will accept at least that much before causing a fault.